# datalist is not working when appending row in table - in mozila

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add row dynamically when user clicks on add row button. My row contains some datalist cells also. but its not working. nothing get displayed in list. Please check and result image and help me to find the bug.

```js
$('html, #addrow').click(function(e) {
  //  alert("i am aa");
  $('#tab_logic tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" list="2" id="inpparameter" ><datalist id="2"><option value="TypeRating">TypeRating</option></td></tr>');
  // add code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tab_logic"> 
<tr><td>Heading</td></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is working

Comment: Are you trying in chrome. did u try in mozila?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this @kavi

```
$('html, #addrow').live("Click",function(e) {
        //  alert("i am aa");
          $('#tab_logic tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" list="2" id="inpparameter" ><datalist id="2"><option value="TypeRating">TypeRating</option></td></tr>');
          // add code here
        });
```

Comment: @prabha: actually this function is happening inside popup function. So when i tried with your code, the pop up was disappeared and i return back to main screen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the problem is with your code, maybe you don't have jQuery? Look at the snippet I created, it works correctly.

```js
$('html, #addrow').click(function(e) {
    $('#tab_logic tr:last').after('<tr><td><input type="text" list="2" id="inpparameter" ><datalist id="2"><option value="TypeRating">TypeRating</option></td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<html>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <button id="addrow">Add row</button>

  <table id="tab_logic">
    <tr>
      <td>asdf</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</html>
```